# Calculate how many cells fit on the screen

Tags: android, gridview

I have a gridview in an android app. The gridview cannot be scrollable, so I need to calculate how many elements fit the screen...

The size of each element varies according to the number of columns that the user chooses in the app...

Here is an image to illustrate this:

[image]

So, in this case the user chooses 5 columns, so my elements will have that size, and the maximum number of elements is 20... (4 lines)
...

How can I calculate the size and number of elements?

Comment: Who can define the max num of elements

Comment: you need to create custom gridview

Comment: I'll try to create a custom gridview...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
yourGridView.getLastVisiblePosition() - yourGridView.getFirstVisiblePosition() + 1;
```